# Play 2.1 JSON to Scala object

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a Scala case class

```
case class Example(name: String, number: Int)
```

and a companion object

```
object Example {
  implicit object ExampleFormat extends Format[Example] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = {
      JsSuccess(Example(
       (json \ "name").as[String],
       (json \ "number").as[Int]))
     }

     def writes(...){}
   }
}
```

which converts JSON to Scala object.

When JSON is valid (i.e. `{"name":"name","number": 0}` it works fine. However, when `number` is in quotes `{"name":"name","number":"0"}` I get an error: `validate.error.expected.jsnumber`.

Is there a way to implicitly convert `String` to `Int` in such a case (assuming that the number is valid) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily handle this case with the Json combinators, thanks to the [`orElse`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L46) helper. I rewrote your json formater with the new syntax introduced by Play2.1

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object Example {
  // Custom reader to handle the "String number" usecase
  implicit val reader = (
    (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
    ((__ \ 'number).read[Int] orElse (__ \ 'number).read[String].map(_.toInt))
  )(Example.apply _)

  // write has no specificity, so you can use Json Macro
  implicit val writer = Json.writes[Example] 
}

object Test extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    val json1 = Json.obj("name" -> "Julien", "number" -> 1000).as[Example]
    val json2 = Json.obj("name" -> "Julien", "number" -> "1000").as[Example]
    Ok(json1.number + " = " + json2.number) // 1000 = 1000
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the job. But is there some more generic solution. For example if I had fields like number1, number2... ?

Comment: There are certainly better ways to do this, but look at this solution https://gist.github.com/02dca6d1b77f0be6bf72